# C# FSM for multiple NPC types

Tags: unity, c#, fsm

Okay, so this is going to be a bit of code that I kind of need help with.

**Foreword**

The code below describes an implementation of an FSM now since I am using unity this allows me to create assets out of my states/actions and decisions.

**States**

```
[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "PluggableAI/States")]
public class State : ScriptableObject
{
    public Action[] actions;
    public Transition[] transitions;
    public Color sceneGizmoColor = Color.grey;
    public EnumProfession Profession;

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates current state
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="controller"></param>
    public void UpdateState(StateController controller)
    {
        DoActions(controller);
        CheckTransitions(controller);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Does each action
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="controller"></param>
    private void DoActions(StateController controller)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < actions.Length; i++)
        {
            actions[i].Act(controller);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check which transition we have to ggo in
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="controller"></param>
    private void CheckTransitions(StateController controller)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < transitions.Length; i++)
        {
            bool decisionSucceeded = transitions[i].decision.Decide(controller);

            if (decisionSucceeded)
            {
                controller.TransitionToState(transitions[i].trueState);
            }
            else
            {
                controller.TransitionToState(transitions[i].falseState);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Action**

```
    public abstract class Action : ScriptableObject
{
    public abstract void Act(StateController controller);
}
```

**Decision**

```
public abstract class Decision : ScriptableObject
{
    public abstract bool Decide (StateController controller);
}
```

**Transition**

```
public class Transition
{
    public Decision decision;
    public State trueState;
    public State falseState;
}
```

To control the states and its transitions I have created the following class `StateController`:

```
    public class StateController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public State CurrentState;
    public State RemainState;
    public NpcHuman NpcHuman;

    /// <summary>
    /// When the game starts
    /// </summary>
    private void Awake()
    {
        if (NpcHuman == null)
        {
            NpcHuman = GetComponent<NpcHuman>();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates every frame
    /// </summary>
    void Update()
    {
        CurrentState.UpdateState(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Transitions to next state
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="nextState"></param>
    public void TransitionToState(State nextState)
    {
        if (nextState != RemainState)
        {
            CurrentState = nextState;
            onExitState();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Is Called everytime a state exits
    /// </summary>
    private void onExitState()
    {
    }

    public void ForceChangeState(State state)
    {
        CurrentState = state;
    }
}
```

Now what ive done is that i have identified the different types of AI's that i have in my game depending on their type:

**Types of NPC's**

```
Villager  - Humanoid

Soldier  - Humanoid

Archer - Humanoid

Catapult (vehicles)  - Generic

Spirits - Generic

Animals - Generic
```

Now let's start with the Humanoid characters for this I have created the following relationship:

[image]

Now as you can see each of the humanoid classes derives from the class `NpcHumanoid` *Edit - There was an error with my naming in the chart sorry*

If you have been paying close attention you would already see that there is an issue with this code.

My main problem right now is the reference to the different types of objects.

**So my question is what is the best way to do this?**

Should I create an abstract class for the state machine and then create subclasses of that that can then hold a reference for which AI/NPC type it's controlling. And how would that work with my states? seeing as they all take a StateController as a parameter I would constantly have to `cast` the statecontroller to the type that is using the state (which just seems slobby and spaghetti ish)

Also, there might be a solution that I am not seeing I would love to get input from you guys.

A final note I did not know which section of Stack exchange I should post this on. It is game development however it is very code heavy. So if I should post it on StackOverflow please do not hesitate to comment and il move the post to that section.

Comment: How does the Generic NPC differ from the NPCHumanoid?

Comment: @DMGregory Certain functions and values does not exists in the Generic setup they may have other visual capabilities and movement

Comment: Those 2 things feel like separate systems you should be able to apply to any entity.